# Docusign JWT authentication returns no valid keys or signatures error in Java but works fine with JavaScript why?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jwt, key, rsa

To work with docusign JWT Sign  [(documentation)](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken) ,The JWS creation works fine with java script with  [this library](http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/jsrsasign-latest-all-min.js) with the following code. but its not working with Java implementation using `io.jsonwebtoken`

```
var currTime = Math.round(Date.now()/1000);
var expTime = currTime+3600;

var header = {
    "alg": "RS256"
};

var data = {
    "iat": currTime,
    "exp" : expTime,
    "iss": "xxxx",
    "sub": "xxxx",
    "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
    "scope": "impersonation signature"
};

var secret = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----XXXXX-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

var sHeader = JSON.stringify(header);
var sPayload = JSON.stringify(data);
var jws = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign("RS256", sHeader, sPayload, secret);
```

The Java implementation

```
    final String ISS = "xxxx";
    final String SUB = "xxxx";
    final String AUD = "account-d.docusign.com";
    final String SCOPE = "impersonation signature";
    final String SECRET =
            "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\nXXXXX\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

    Long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Long expTime = currTime+3600;
    Map<String,Object> header = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    header.put("alg","RS256");
    data.put("iat",currTime);
    data.put("exp",expTime);
    data.put("iss",ISS);
    data.put("sub",SUB);
    data.put("aud",AUD);
    data.put("scope",SCOPE);
    java.security.Security.addProvider(
            new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider()
    );

    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); // or "EC" or whatever
    PemObject pem = new PemReader(new StringReader(SECRET)).readPemObject();
    byte[] der = pem.getContent();
    PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(der));

    String jws = Jwts.builder()
            .setHeader(header)
            .setClaims(data)
            .signWith(privateKey, SignatureAlgorithm.RS256)
            .compact();
```

which returns the following 400 error.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "no_valid_keys_or_signatures"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry its my mistake the timestamp makes the error `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000` fixed the issue

```
final String ISS = "xxxx";
final String SUB = "xxxx";
final String AUD = "account-d.docusign.com";
final String SCOPE = "impersonation signature";
final String SECRET =
        "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\nXXXXX\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

Long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
Long expTime = currTime+3600;
Map<String,Object> header = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,Object> data = new HashMap<>();
header.put("alg","RS256");
data.put("iat",currTime);
data.put("exp",expTime);
data.put("iss",ISS);
data.put("sub",SUB);
data.put("aud",AUD);
data.put("scope",SCOPE);
java.security.Security.addProvider(
        new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider()
);

KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); // or "EC" or whatever
PemObject pem = new PemReader(new StringReader(SECRET)).readPemObject();
byte[] der = pem.getContent();
PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(der));

String jws = Jwts.builder()
        .setHeader(header)
        .setClaims(data)
        .signWith(privateKey, SignatureAlgorithm.RS256)
        .compact();
```